# In Javascript, is function a data type in itself or does it fall under the object data type (like arrays)?

Tags: javascript, function, object

According to the latest version of **Javascript**, is **function** a data type in itself or does it fall under the object data type (like arrays)?

why does

```
let array1 = [1,2,3];

typeof(array1);
```

return "**object**"

whereas

```
 function myFunction() {
      alert("Hello World!");
    }
    typeof(myFunction)
```

return "**function**"?

these two MDN articles are confusing me as one says there are 8 data types and the other one says there are 9.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#data_types

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#data_and_structure_types

Comment: It's similar to `number`. They're primitive values, but they can also be boxed into the `Number` object type so you can call methods from the prototype.

Comment: typeof operator: typeof instance === "function"

Comment: @Barmar that first linked article, which uses capitalized names for the primitive types, should probably be fixed. (Sadly that's true of lots of the MDN tutorial "essay" pages.) e: in fact both of those pages are misleading.

Comment: A function is an object. The Function constructor has its own prototype. (Any constructor can have its own prototype.) All functions are objects, but not all objects are functions. Those MDN articles are misleading and not very well-written. I would strongly suggest finding a better tutorial resource for the language.

Comment: @Pointy To be fair, this is an inherently confusing aspect of the language.

Comment: @Barmar yes of course, I completely agree, but that's why I think those pages aren't helping things.

Comment: @pointy: which other tutorials/documentation do you recommend I use instead?

Comment: @shashah there are *many* quality books out there. Don't get me wrong, MDN is a great resource, but the "factual" pages that describe APIs etc are much more reliable than those "introduction" pages, because people who know how things work are much more likely to update those.